# Historical Balance from a transactaion table

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

| customer_id | transacting date | day_end_balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 523161 | 7/2/2021 | 136.2 |
| 523161 | 6/14/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/7/2021 | 0 |
| 523161 | 6/2/2021 | 440 |

So the balance shows up when a transaction occurs and the balance remains unchanged at the end of the day if no transaction occurs. I want to create a table that shows the day end balance per customer from the beginning of a customer's life till today. Check below table for the desired output.

| customer_id | transacting date | day_end_balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 523161 | 6/2/2021 | 440 |
| 523161 | 6/3/2021 | 440 |
| ...... | ............ | ..... |
| 523161 | 6/7/2021 | 0 |
| 523161 | 6/8/2021 | 0 |
| 523161 | 6/9/2021 | 0 |
| 523161 | 6/10/2021 | 0 |
| 523161 | 6/11/2021 | 0 |
| 523161 | 6/12/2021 | 0 |
| 523161 | 6/13/2021 | 0 |
| 523161 | 6/14/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/14/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/15/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/16/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/17/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/18/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/19/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/20/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/21/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/22/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/23/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/24/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/25/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/26/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/27/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/28/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/29/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 6/30/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 7/1/2021 | 215.4 |
| 523161 | 7/2/2021 | 136.2 |
| 523161 | .... | 136.2 |
| 523161 | date of today | 136.2 |

How do i do this in postgres sql? I know it would involve last_value() and coalesce(), and possibly lag() and lead(). But not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_series()` to get all days between the minimum day for a customer and today and lateral join that selecting the data of the top most day less than or equal the respective day in the series.

```
SELECT cjl."customer_id",
       gs."transacting date",
       cjl."day_end_balance"
       FROM generate_series((SELECT min(t."transacting date")
                                    FROM elbat t
                                    WHERE t."customer_id" = 523161),
                            current_date,
                            '1 day'::interval) gs
                                               ("transacting date")
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT t."customer_id",
                                       t."day_end_balance"
                                       FROM elbat t
                                       WHERE t."customer_id" = 523161
                                             AND t."transacting date" <= gs."transacting date"
                                       ORDER BY t."transacting date" DESC
                                       LIMIT 1) cjl
       ORDER BY gs."transacting date";
```